# porting package to newer ubuntu version

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, compiling

i want to port a package (tremulous) from 12.04 to 14.04 and 16.04. i never worked with ubuntu packages so i need some guidance.
i did
    sudo apt-get build-dep tremulous
    sudo apt-get source tremulous

and i got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
NOTICE: 'tremulous' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
git://git.debian.org/git/pkg-games/tremulous.git
Need to get 2956 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse tremulous 1.1.0-5 (dsc) [1850 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse tremulous 1.1.0-5 (tar) [2931 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse tremulous 1.1.0-5 (diff) [23.7 kB]                                                              
Fetched 2956 kB in 16s (180 kB/s)                                                                                                                          
gpgv: Signature made Sat Jul 17 14:31:45 2010 UTC using RSA key ID 63C7CC90
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./tremulous_1.1.0-5.dsc
dpkg-source: info: extracting tremulous in tremulous-1.1.0
dpkg-source: info: unpacking tremulous_1.1.0.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking tremulous_1.1.0-5.debian.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: applying 0001-add-upstream-Makefile.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0002-Avoid-building-game-logic-as-QVMs.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0003-Don-t-build-q3lcc.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0004-Use-USER-as-default-player-name.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0005-Fix-unaligned-access-issue.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0006-fix-abuse-of-strcpy-overlapping-source-and-dest.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0007-Fix-to-disappearing-cursor-on-map-load-Com_Error-bug.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0008-Fixed-sort-by-ping.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0009-Disable-JIT-QVM-interpreter-on-x86-64.patch
```

in my folder i found 4 new entries. what are they? `tremulous_1.1.0.orig.tar.gz` origina sources? `tremulous_1.1.0-5.debian.tar.gz` debian patches and scripts? `tremulous_1.1.0-5.dsc` signatures? and a folder: `tremulous-1.1.0`.

what exactly is this folder? does it have patches already applied or should i apply them on my own? if so, how? and what then? which goal execute from the Makefile? is there any standard way of compiling  ubuntu's packages? is it the same between ubuntu versions?

Comment: downloading the debian installer and using dpkg did not work? " is it the same between ubuntu versions?" yes.

Comment: by 'debian installer' you mean 'debian's package'? sources or binaries? how? any commands? any hints? i know nothing about ubuntu/debian packaging

Comment: 1st thing I would do is download the .DEB for an older releases and try to install it using dpkg. If that works you do not need to create a package yourself.

Comment: it worked (checked with 14.04), thank you! but it's just reinstalling binary. i would like to have sources, be able to modify then if needed (future versions), build binaries and install. where should i start?